# Thermostat wiring in need of fixing

Tags: thermostat

I am trying to install a new smart thermostat and the control wire is not working     (*it controlled the heat fine in the winter*.)

I came out to my air handler and this is the wiring I’m looking at and need help.

Can anyone tell me if this is worth trying to do my self or should I call?

file:///var/mobile/Library/SMS/Attachments/a4/04/BF222EFD-41B6-4DB4-A4EE-3B96FBC9FD12/63908660703__420E202F-1BAB-46B6-99D2-36C7959E96E9.HEIC

Comment: The file location of your photo on your hard drive  is not showing us the photo.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: If you took a photo of how the original thermostat was hooked up that might be faster like RC had a pink wire fan or F had a green , not everyone uses the common wire colors do seeing how they were connected to the original thermostat may be the fastest way to get it working properly.

Comment: Yeah, can you [edit] your post and fix the busted phtoo link?